# WorkManager adding too many jobs to JobScheduler

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I'm trying to schedule a task to run at a specific time using `WorkManager`. I'm using `beginUniqueWork` as I want only one task scheduled at a time for that specific ID (uniqueWorkName). But after calling `enqueue` multiple times, at some point I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Apps may not schedule more than 100 distinct jobs
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2012)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
    at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.schedule(IJobScheduler.java:180)
    at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.schedule(JobSchedulerImpl.java:44)
    at androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobScheduler.scheduleInternal(SystemJobScheduler.java:85)
    at androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobScheduler.schedule(SystemJobScheduler.java:64)
    at androidx.work.impl.Schedulers.scheduleInternal(Schedulers.java:98)
    at androidx.work.impl.Schedulers.schedule(Schedulers.java:69)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.rescheduleEligibleWork(WorkManagerImpl.java:398)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

When I log the number of pending jobs using the following snippet after every `enqueue`, I noticed that there are 3 new jobs added to the list for every call (while I expect the total to stay at 1).

```
JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
int size = jobScheduler.getAllPendingJobs().size();
```

Here is the code I'm using to schedule tasks:

```
val work = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(workerClass)
        .setInitialDelay(offset, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build()
WorkManager.getInstance()
        .beginUniqueWork(uniqueNameForTask, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, work)
        .enqueue()
```

Does anything look off here? What am I missing?

Comment: What's your current worker version ?

Comment: Was 1.0.0-alpha01. Upgrading to 1.0.0-alpha07 solved the issue 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [WorkManager 1.0.0-alpha07 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes#august_16_2018), one of the fixes for 1.0.0-alpha07 was:

> Work that has finished execution now correctly cancels all pending copies of that work in other Schedulers. This led to exceeding the JobScheduler jobs limit. [b/111569265](https://issuetracker.google.com/111569265)

So upgrading to 1.0.0-alpha07 should fix your issue.